# Comparing DateOffsets in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Is there a way to compare the size of two `DateOffset` objects?

```
>>> from pandas.core.datetools import *
>>> Hour(24) > Minute(5)
False
```

This works with `timedelta`, so I assumed that pandas would inherit that behavior - or is the time system made from scratch?

Comment: As of pandas 0.19.2, the comparison correctly evaluates to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas DateOffsets does not inherit from timedelta. It's possible for some DateOffsets to be compared, but for offsets like MonthEnd, MonthStart, etc, the span of time to the next offset is non-uniform and depends on the starting date.

Please feel free to start a github issue on this at https://github.com/pydata/pandas, we can continue the discussion there and it'll serve as a reminder.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so this really serves a different purpose. Thanks - I'll stick to timedelta for uniform timespans

Comment: @scry: pandas has its own Timedelta object that inherits the behaviour of datetime.timedelta: pd.Timedelta(hours=24) > pd.Timedelta(minutes=5) returns the correct result.